# Hadoop Graph input - Chaining Jobs

Tags: hadoop, graph, mapreduce, bigdata, hadoop2

I have an input file in the following format.

```
input.txt
1, 1   2
2, 1   3
3, 2   3
4, 1   4
```

The above input file has a key which is line number and the value as the graph edges of an undirected graph. For example for the first record,the line number is 1 and edge is between 1 and 2.. In the map logic I have to find which vertice has the low order degree. How would I do.Please, help me out as am newbie to Hadoop-map reduce.

Answer (score 0):

For Identifying the vertex with the lowest degree in a graph we have two implement two jobs. This is called **Chaining Jobs in Hadoop MapReduce Programming**

**JOB 1**

Job one will calculate degree for each and every vertex. Reducer will save the output to a HDFS folder.

**JOB 2**

Job 2 will read the output of the job 1 as input and find the vertex with the lowest degree.

Please find below the detailed code written in JAVA. Arguments for the program are the input text file and output file

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class LowestDegreeOfGraph {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);  

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Text word = new Text();
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }                       
        }   
    }


    public static class MapForFindingLowDegree extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {


        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Text word = new Text();
            String[] line = value.toString().split("\t");

            context.write(new Text("vertexWithLowestDegree"), new Text(line[0]+","+line[1]));                   
        }   
    }


    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {


        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();             
            }

            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));           

        }       

    }

public static class ReduceForFindingLowDegree extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {


        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int flag = 0;
            int vertex=0;
            int degree=0;
            for (Text value : values) {
                String[]    line=value.toString().split(",");
                if(flag==0){
                    vertex=Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
                    degree=Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    flag=1;
                }else if(degree>Integer.parseInt(line[1])){
                    vertex=Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
                    degree=Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                }
            }

            context.write(new Text("Vertex with the lowest degree "+vertex),new Text("Degree "+degree));            

        }       

    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        Configuration conf=new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:8020");
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(LowestDegreeOfGraph.class);
        job.setJobName("For calculating the degree for every vertex");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/opt/"));
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);    

        Job job2 = new Job(conf);
        job2.setJarByClass(LowestDegreeOfGraph.class);
        job2.setJobName("Identifying the Vertex with lowest degree");
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path("/opt/"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path((args[1])));
        job2.setMapperClass(MapForFindingLowDegree.class);
        job2.setReducerClass(ReduceForFindingLowDegree.class);
        job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job2.waitForCompletion(true);   

    }




}
```

arg[0] is the input file. PFB the sample input file.
Sample input file 
1   2
1   3
2   3
1   4

arg[1] is the location for the output file.

Kindly provide arg[0] and arg[1] while running the JOB.

/opt is the temporary location for storing the temp data.

Comment: Hi Nithin, I am working on it. Can you add comments to the code of lines. I didnt get clearly, of what the input at each step will be..Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nithin, Can u please provide input and output at each mapper and reducer .

Comment: Answer updated for input and output. Kindly let me know if you have any queries. Please accept the answer if it is right

Comment: Throws Arrays out of bound exception and generates first reducer output and second reducer output is not generated.

Comment: Array out of bond exception means in your input file may contain an extra new line . Please remove the new line and re execute the program . Whenever you are executing a map reduce program you have to provide new output path for every reducer

Comment: Thanks a lot Nithin. I got it working.How should I accept the solution here?